# Getting empty character literal error in java code that specified unicode literals

Tags: java, unicode, unicode-literals

Why does this code

```
 public class Apostrophier
{
    public static String replace(String s)
    {
        return s.replace('\u0092','\u0027');
    }
}
```

give

'empty character literal'

when I try to compile ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The unicode code points in the source file are replaced by the actual character they represents. Since `'\u0027'` is for `'` (apostrophe). So, your return statement is replaced to:

```
  return s.replace('\u0092',''');
```

*Note:* `\u0092` will also be replaced by control character.

So, the 2nd argument is an invalid character literal. You can rather use `\'` directly.

Comment: You could also say `s.replace('\u0092','\u005c\u0027')` !!!  Not that you'd want to.  (`\u005c` is a backslash.)

Answer (score 5):

Replacing the unicode sequences is a very early step of the compilation process.  In particular, it happens before parsing literals.  So when it's time to parse the literals, `\u0027` has already been replaced with `'`.  Therefore, after the comma, you have `'''`, which the compiler can't make sense of.